# how can we disable the checkbox field in knokout.js with ko.observable()?

Tags: knockout.js, binding

I'm trying to disable the checkbox for specific field on the base of condition,

```
if (value == 3)
ko.observable(value);
```

Comment: Refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_disabled.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The enable binding causes the associated DOM element to be enabled only when the parameter value is true. This is useful with form elements like input, select, and textarea.

```
<p>
    <input type='checkbox' data-bind="checked: hasCellphone" />
    I have a cellphone
</p>
<p>
    Your cellphone number:
    <input type='text' data-bind="value: cellphoneNumber, enable: hasCellphone" />
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        hasCellphone : ko.observable(false),
        cellphoneNumber: ""
    };
</script>
```

In this example, the “Your cellphone number” text box will initially be disabled. It will be enabled only when the user checks the box labelled “I have a cellphone”. You could do the same thing to disable.

Source - [knockoutjs.com](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this condition with the [`enable`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html) binding via either

#### A) The view

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="enable: value() != 3" />
```

Or,

#### B) in a `ko.pureComputed` or `ko.computed`:

```
const checkboxEnabled = ko.pureComputed(() => value() != 3);
```

Note that I'm using `!=` instead of `!==` because in my example, the value is returned by the view as a string instead of a number.

In action:

```js
const value = ko.observable(3);
const enabled = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  return value() != 3;
});

ko.applyBindings({ value, enabled });
```

```css
label { display: block }
input:disabled + span { color: grey; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="number" data-bind="textInput: value" />
  The reference value
</label>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="enable: enabled" />
  <span>Using a <code>ko.pureComputed</code></span>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="enable: value() != 3" />
  <span>Using a data-bind</span>
</label>
```